# Expand cell in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have several Views arranged in rectangular grid (using GridView). Now I want to expand tapped view so that it occupies the whole row (i. e. the view should grow in one or two direction depends on the column as it is indicated by red arrows in the picure below). 
The transition should be animated.

What is better approach: modify views inside the grid or display another view on top of the GridView and resize it so that it covers selected row?

[image: Rectangular grid]